# How to modify a value from a JSON array per API request using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm doing toggl reports using the `Toggl API` and i notice that the maximum of fields that returns per request is 50, in the documentation says that if you want to get more than that you have increase the value of `per_page` in the JSON array, i tried, and when i do the logger.log seems it works, but really doesn't returns more than the initial 50

***Toggl Report API documentation***

https://github.com/toggl/toggl_api_docs/blob/master/reports/detailed.md

***This is how i do the request***

```js
var baseURL = 'https://www.toggl.com';
  var userToken = '40532ca98780267d0b87da9d1d983k2f'; //Insert API token here
  var string = userToken +':api_token'
  var headers = {'Authorization':'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(string)}
  var options = {'headers': headers};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseURL + '/api/v8/me', options);

  if (response.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    Logger.log('API request failed');
  }

  var res = JSON.parse(response);
  var email = 'jose@gmail.com';
  var workspaces = res['data']['workspaces'];
  var workspaceId = 322923;

  var params = '?user_agent=' + email + '&workspace_id=' + workspaceId.toString()
  var projectURL = baseURL + '/api/v8/workspaces/' + workspaceId.toString() + '/projects' + params;
  var projectsFetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(projectURL, options);
  var projects = JSON.parse(projectsFetch.getContentText());

  var datenow = new Date() 
  var firtsday = new Date(datenow.getFullYear(),datenow.getMonth(), 1)
  var lastday = new Date(datenow.getFullYear(),datenow.getMonth()+1, 0)
  var startDate = Utilities.formatDate(firtsday, 'MT', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  var endDate = Utilities.formatDate(lastday, 'MT', 'yyyy-MM-dd');

  var params = '?user_agent=' + email + '&workspace_id=' + workspaceId.toString() + '&since=' + startDate + '&until=' + endDate;

  var reportURL = baseURL + '/reports/api/v2/details' + params;
  var reportFetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(reportURL, options);
  var togglReport = JSON.parse(reportFetch.getContentText());
  Logger.log(togglReport['per_page']);
```

`togglReport['per_page']`  is the value from the JSON array i have to increase in the second time i do the request, i tried to increase it putting `togglReport['per_page'] = 50;`

*** This is a picture how it looks like the JSON array***

https://www.screencast.com/t/eaFAihNJBCZa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. `togglReport` is the response received. Modifying `togglReport['per_page']` will not change the response that's already received.

Documentation says

> To get the next batch of time entries you need to do a new request with same parameters and the incremented **page** parameter. It is **not possible** to get all the time entries with one request.

If `total_count` is more than `per_page`(i.e., 50), It is needed to call  the api a number of times by adding `page` query parameter. To get the second page, use `?page=2` and `?page=3` for third page so on